# Ansible ad-hoc command with conditionals

Tags: ansible, adhoc

I would like to run an Ansible ad-hoc command of this playbook

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Print message if ansible version is greater than 2.7.0
      debug:
        msg: "Ansible version is  {{ ansible_version.full }}"
      when: ansible_version.full >= "2.7.4"
```

I have this command, how can I include the conditional 'when'?

```
ansible localhost -m debug -a msg="{{ ansible_version.full }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have this command, how can I include the conditional 'when'?

The `when:` is syntatic sugar for a jinja2 `if` statement, so you would use:

```
ansible localhost -m {% if ansible_version.full >= '2.7.4' %}debug{% endif %} -a msg="{{ ansible_version.full }}"
```

As for how to *skip* the task entirely, you'd have to find a module that you could put in there which would cause *nothing* to happen, such as `pause` with `seconds=0` or such, or write your own `noop:` module

---

Also, while I just copied your `when:` statement verbatim, I believe the **correct** condition is to use the [`version` comparison test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison):

```
ansible localhost -m debug -a msg="{% if (ansible_version.full is version('2.7.4', '>=')) %}{{ ansible_version.full }}{% endif %}"
```

because what you have written will be compared lexigraphically and not using version semantics, so `2.10.4` would **not** be considered `>=` `2.7` since `2.1` appears earlier in a sorted list than `2.7`

Comment: Looks like I would not be able to use the fail module to fail if version is < "2.7.4". When I use the adhoc command above(replacing 'debug' with 'fail') the command fails irrespective.

Comment: _the command fails irrespective_
What does that mean? `ansible -v -i localhost, -c local -m '{% if 1 == 1 %}debug{% else %}fail{% endif %}' '*'` does exactly as I said, and changing to `1 == 0` invokes the `fail` module