# How can I use a `when` clause in an ansible ad-hoc command?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to see the value of an Ansible host variable, `xsp_server`, for all the hosts in my inventory that have `xsp_server` defined.  So I execute this commmand:

```
ansible all -i inventory/production -o -m debug \
-a msg="{% if (xsp_server is defined) %}{{ xsp_server }}{% else %}'notdefined'{% endif %}" \
| grep -v notdefined
```

The above command I got from this question here: [Ansible ad-hoc command with conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876213/ansible-ad-hoc-command-with-conditionals)

I would like to avoid having to use the `| grep -v notdefined`, but if I don't use the grep I get a lot of noise.  I would like to be able to execute:

```
ansible all -i inventory/production -o -m debug \
-a msg="{% if (xsp_server is defined) %}{{ xsp_server }}{% endif %}"
```

and just see output when `xsp_server` is defined, but I still get a bunch of ...

```
SUCCESS => {    "changed": false,    "msg": ""}
```

... lines in my output.

Comment: You cannot use a `when` command in an ad-hoc command (that is playbook syntax that's only available when you're writing a playbook).

Comment: Note that `msg="{% if (xsp_server is defined) %}{{ xsp_server }}{% endif %}"` can be simplified to `msg="{{ xsp_server | d('') }}`

Answer (score 2):

As reported by @larsks, you cannot use a `when` clause in an ad-hoc command. Meanwhile, for the above specific case, you might achieve a similar result closer to what you expect with something like:

```
ANSIBLE_LOAD_CALLBACK_PLUGINS=1 \
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=ansible.posix.json \
ansible localhost -i inventory/production -m debug \
-a msg="{% set result = {} %}\
{% for s in groups['all'] %}\
{% if hostvars[s].xsp_server is defined %}\
{{ result.update({s: hostvars[s].xsp_server}) }}\
{% endif %}\
{% endfor %}\
{{ result }}" \
| jq ".plays[0].tasks[0].hosts.localhost.msg"
```